# Как вызывать функцию в if?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я реально не могу понять.

```js
let activeSlide = 0
let time = 0
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  time++
  if (time == 5)
  slideRight()
}, 1000);

buttons[1].click(function slideRight() {

тут функция слайдера
});
```

Я видимо как то не правлиьно пытаюсь вывести функцию в `if` то есть я ее не правильно записываю или что? Почему алерт вызывается а функция нет?

Comment: что за алерт? почему ты думаешь что функция не вызывается?

Comment: Потому что ничего не просходит, alert('!!!') выполняется, а функция нет
let time = 0
var timerId = setInterval(function () {
  time++
 console.log(time)
 if(time == 5)
 slideRight()
 time = 0
}, 1000);
Когда я записываю так, то по какой то причине time не прибавляет одну единицу каждую секунду, а просто пишет 1, 1 , 1 , 1 причем повторами в консоле,

Comment: Оказывается еще у меня пишет что slideRight не опеределен

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: slideRight is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы функция была доступна по имени ее нужно определять отдельно:

```
function slideRight() {
    // тут функция слайдера
}
```

В данном же случае

```
.click(function slideRight() {... })
```

имя `slideRight` доступно только внутри самой функции. Поэтому и получается указанная ошибка.

Решением может стать такой код:

```
let activeSlide = 0
let time = 0
function slideRight() {
    // тут функция слайдера
}

var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  time++
  if (time == 5)
  slideRight()
}, 1000);

buttons[1].click(sliderRight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons[1].click(function() {
   slideRight();
});
```